# Underscore debounce for each different argument

Tags: underscore.js

Is there a nice way to get a similar behavior for `_.debounce` but with the difference that every changed argument is executed once? eg:

```
foo = function (arg) {console.log(arg)}
lazy = _.debounce(foo,1000)

lazy("a")
lazy("a")
lazy("a")
lazy("a")
lazy("b")
a // with debounce "a" would not be printed
b // but i would like run the debounced function once for every changed arg.
```

Answer (score 2):

Fo the lack of an better solution i came up with this:

```
args = {}
function markAllAsUnread(rooms) {
    _.each(rooms,function (roomname) {
        // Here i do my heavy work....
        console.log(roomname)
    })
    args = {}
}

markAllAsUnreadLazy = _.debounce(markAllAsUnread,2000)

function markAsUnread (arg) {
    args[arg] = arg // to unify the given args
    markAllAsUnreadLazy(args)
}


markAsUnread (1)
markAsUnread (1)
markAsUnread (123)
markAsUnread (123123)
markAsUnread (123123)
markAsUnread (123123)
markAsUnread (12334)

1
123
12334
123123
```